# Why dot operator can not access array elements?

Tags: javascript

This question is about JavaScript language fundamentals. Why we can use dot (`.`) operator to access an object's elements but not for array elements?

In other words why `myArray.0` is not valid in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A javascript property name accessed with the dot notation cannot start with a number.  That's just part of the javascript syntax rules/grammar.  So, even if dot notation could work for arrays, it won't because array indexes are numbers and property names that start with numbers cannot be accessed with dot notation.

For arrays, you can obviously use:

```
myArray[0]
```

But, that also works for object properties that start with a number like:

```
var x = {"12": "foo"};
alert(x["12"]);     // foo
```

And, you cannot do:

```
alert(x.12)
```

even when `x` is an object and `"12"` is a legitimate property on the object.  You would have to use `x["12"]` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Why? Because that is the javascript syntax. As simple as that.

You use `[x]` to get the element at the x index not `.x`

Answer (score 0):

The property name in the dot notation must be a valid JavaScript id. Any object property name which is not a valid id cannot be used in the dot notation, whether in an object or an array. For such property names, the [] notation must be used where the property name is a string, or is converted to a string.

Note that you can use the dot nodation with arrays to get its length for example since 'length' IS a valid id.

Answer (score 0):

So just to expand on jfriend00's reply - the following will work because the property name begins with a letter not a number

```
var test = new Array();
test['zero'] = "Testing";
alert(test.zero); // Does work
```

Comment: Just to be clear here.  `zero` in this case is a property of the `test` object, not an array element.  Arrays have both array elements and properties and the two are not quite the same.  For example, you would find that `test.length == 0`.

Comment: See... learnt something already, I knew joining this site would be a good idea :) Thanks jfriend!